# How to setup private npm registry authentication in dockerfile

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile

Currently use my own private npm.

In my local, i always need to login to my own private npm first and install all the packages to my project

```
npm login --registry https://nodenpm.XXXX.co  # to login private npm registry
 > Enter username
 > Enter password
npm install --registry https://nodenpm.XXXX.co  # to install the deps from private registry
```

In the dockerfile, how do I log in to my own private npm and install?

This is my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm login --registry=https://nodenpm.XXXX.co -u <username> -p <password>

RUN npm install --registry https://nodenpm.XXXX.co --save

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "node", "/app/dist/main" ]
```

But it has fail to build in docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Branyac and based on his answer.

Make sure you have .npmrc file

In my docker file, I removed all the login info and added

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=npm,target=/root/.npmrc npm install --registry https://nodenpm.XXXX.co
```

Then in the CMD run

```
docker build . -t <image name> --secret id=npm,src=$HOME/.npmrc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to include user and password credentials directly inside a Dockerfile due to security risks. Instead, you should store npm registry credentials in the `.npmrc`[1](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc) file.

You should remove `npm login` from your dockerfile and mount the .npmrc file as a [Docker secret](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypesecret) in the correct path (Typically, the npmrc file is located at $HOME/.npmrc).